# Настройка webpack`a

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp

Как можно настроить webpack, чтобы он работал с gulp-file-include

```
@@include('component/app.js')
```

Ошибка :

```
Error in plugin "webpack-stream"
Message:
    Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (3:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
> @@include('component/app.js')
```

Comment: "@@include" никогда такую запись не встречал, это вообще валидно?

Comment: @pyduti это gulp-file-include, написал же )